# Existe algum comando que faça a função recomeçar?

Tags: javascript

Sou novo nesta área. Criei este bot para um site de apostas. Gostaria de saber se existe algum comando para que a função volte ao início quando sair verde.

```
$("input").val("10");
setTimeout(function(){
$(".btn-bet.green").click();
    }, 100);
setTimeout(function(){
$("input").val("11");
$(".btn-bet.green").click();
    }, 25000);
setTimeout(function(){
$("input").val("13");
$(".btn-bet.green").click();
    }, 50000);
setTimeout(function(){
$("input").val("13");
$(".btn-bet.green").click();
    }, 75000);
setTimeout(function(){
$("input").val("13");
$(".btn-bet.green").click();
    }, 100000);
setTimeout(function(){
$("input").val("13");
$(".btn-bet.green").click();
    }, 125000);
setTimeout(function(){
$("input").val("13");
$(".btn-bet.green").click();
    }, 150000);
setTimeout(function(){
$("input").val("13");
$(".btn-bet.green").click();
    }, 175000);
setTimeout(function(){
$("input").val("13");
$(".btn-bet.green").click();
    }, 200000);
setTimeout(function(){
$("input").val("13");
$(".btn-bet.green").click();
    }, 225000);
setTimeout(function(){
$("input").val("13");
$(".btn-bet.green").click();
    }, 250000);
setTimeout(function(){
$("input").val("13");
$(".btn-bet.green").click();
    }, 275000);
setTimeout(function(){
$("input").val("13");
$(".btn-bet.green").click();
    }, 300000);
setTimeout(function(){
$("input").val("13");
$(".btn-bet.green").click();
    }, 325000);
setTimeout(function(){
$("input").val("13");
$(".btn-bet.green").click();
    }, 350000);
setTimeout(function(){
$("input").val("13");
$(".btn-bet.green").click();
    }, 375000);
setTimeout(function(){
$("input").val("13");
$(".btn-bet.green").click();
    }, 400000);
setTimeout(function(){
$("input").val("13");
$(".btn-bet.green").click();
    }, 425000);
setTimeout(function(){
$("input").val("13");
$(".btn-bet.green").click();
    }, 450000);
setTimeout(function(){
$("input").val("13");
$(".btn-bet.green").click();
    }, 475000);
setTimeout(function(){
$("input").val("13");
$(".btn-bet.green").click();
    }, 500000);
setTimeout(function(){
$("input").val("13");
$(".btn-bet.green").click();
    }, 525000);
setTimeout(function(){
$("input").val("13");
$(".btn-bet.green").click();
    }, 550000);
setTimeout(function(){
$("input").val("13");
$(".btn-bet.green").click();
    }, 575000);
setTimeout(function(){
$("input").val("13");
$(".btn-bet.green").click();
    }, 600000);
setTimeout(function(){
$("input").val("13");
$(".btn-bet.green").click();
    }, 625000);
setTimeout(function(){
$("input").val("13");
$(".btn-bet.green").click();
    }, 650000);
setTimeout(function(){
$("input").val("13");
$(".btn-bet.green").click();
    }, 675000);
setTimeout(function(){
$("input").val("13");
$(".btn-bet.green").click();
    }, 700000);
setTimeout(function(){
$("input").val("13");
$(".btn-bet.green").click();
    }, 725000);
setTimeout(function(){
$("input").val("13");
$(".btn-bet.green").click();
    }, 750000);
setTimeout(function(){
$("input").val("13");
$(".btn-bet.green").click();
    }, 775000);
setTimeout(function(){
$("input").val("13");
$(".btn-bet.green").click();
    }, 800000);
```

Comment: Por favor, não digite textos em caixa alta, isso prejudica a leitura. Edite a pergunta acessando o link [edit] e escreva normalmente. Aproveite e faça o [tour] para aprender o básico do site e leia o guia de [ask]. Para formatar corretamente seu código, utilize o botão `{}` do editor.

Comment: Por que você começa com `$("input").val("10");`, depois tem `$("input").val("11");` e todos os outros são `$("input").val("13");`?

Comment: este script é só um teste na verdade quando acerto o verde a quantidade apostada é multiplicada po 14X

Comment: a razão é 1.1x a cada aposta, mas a questãoo é a seguinte, se der green eu gostaria que voltasse ao inicio da função

Comment: existe alum comando return que eu possa usar por exemplo if green return

Comment: este site é formado por 3 cores, vermelho, verde, e preto, no caso a aposta no verde ganha 14x o valor apostado, com esta função eu coloco o valor que quiser a jogar no verde, porém eu queria um comando que identificasse o verde e voltasse à base novamente, ou seja, na primeira aposta

Answer (score 1):

Bem, o seu script seria algo equivalente mais ou menos a isso:

Tentativa 1:

```
function fazApostas() {
    var jaFoi = false;
    $(".btn-bet.green").click(function() {
        jaFoi = true;
        fazApostas();
    });
    var m = 10;
    for (var i = 0; i < 40; i++) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            if (jaFoi) return;
            $("input").val("" + ~~m);
            m *= 1.1;
            $(".btn-bet.green").click();
        }, i * 25000 + 100);
    }
}
fazApostas();
```

Tentativa 2:

```
function fazApostas() {
    var m = 10;
    function aumentarAposta() {
        $("input").val("" + ~~m);
        if ($(".btn-bet.green").length === 0) {
            m *= 1.1;
            setTimeout(aumentarAposta, 25000);
        } else {
            $(".btn-bet.green").click(fazApostas);
            $(".btn-bet.green").click();
        }
    }
    setTimeout(aumentarAposta, 100);
}
fazApostas();
```

- O `$(".btn-bet.green").click(fazApostas);` define o que ele faz quando é clicado. No caso, ele começa tudo de novo.
- O `m *= 1.1;` faz o valor da aposta aumentar a cada vez.
- O `"" + ~~m` serve para converter o `m` para inteiro e depois para string.
- Cada iteração da `aumentarAposta` chama uma outra iteração 25 segundos depois.
- O `$(".btn-bet.green").length === 0` verifica se o botão está presente ou não.

Comment: Mas não há possibilidade de usar uma return?

Comment: Teste o seu script no site e não funcionou, teria outra solução usando a mesma função, exem´plo quando sair o green eu uso uma função que identifica ele

Comment: @RamonSilva Acho que um `return` não vai fazer o que você quer. A função `fazApostas()` apenas cria um monte de eventos a serem executados no futuro e morre imediatamente. Qualquer coisa que ela retornasse não seria lá muito útil. Você até poderia usar um mecanismo de promises/callback, mas provavelmente isso não seria o que você quer.

Comment: @RamonSilva Talvez você queira usar isso: https://api.jquery.com/size/

Comment: @RamonSilva O que deu errado no script?

Comment: O site é este https://csgoatse.com/, notem que debaixo da roleta tem os resultados, por ali gostaria de usar o return, por exemplo quando um green surgir no histórico meu script recomeçasse.

Comment: Ele não aposta, simplesmente não aconteceu nada quando joguei ele no console

Comment: @RamonSilva Script editado. Olhe a última linha.

Comment: Agora eu achei amigão, deu mas ele ta apostando varias vezes seguidas eu gostaria de uma aposta a cada 25 segundos

Comment: Se sair green quero que retorne a base 10

Comment: @RamonSilva Resposta editada.

Comment: O essencial mesmo era um javscript que identificasse os green, gostaria que ele iniciasse a apostar após 30 rounds sem sair verde e quando o verde saísse ele esperasse mais 30 rounds para começar a apostar novamente

Comment: Este travou  a pagina pois ele repete inúmeras vezes as apostas

Comment: @RamonSilva Então ainda não sei. Deixei as duas tentativas aí para caso você ou outra pessoa encontre uma outra solução.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda mesmo assim